# Displaying GIFs on Windows Phone 8.1 (RT or Silverlight)

Tags: image, windows-phone-8.1, gif

How does one play GIFs on Windows Phone 8.1? I tried setting the `Source` property of an `Image` element to a GIF file, but it only loads the first frame. `MediaElement` did not seem to work either. I had the same result in a Store app as well as a WP Silverlight project. Does WP 8.1 natively support GIFs? If not, are there any third-party libraries out there that do the work?

P.S. Ideally, I'd like to not have to use the WebView control to load GIFs.